# Problems with getting header field value from response + java web services

Tags: java, web-services

I am writing a web service client using NetBeans IDE. I have added webservice sources using WSDL and for one of the methods the response POJO class contains for example only two parameters:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "WithdrawTicket")
public class WithdrawTicket {

@XmlAttribute(name = "firstName")
protected String firstName;
@XmlAttribute(name = "lastName")
protected String lastName;
... //getters and setters
```

response XML contains in body part above two fields (firstName and lastName), and also contains header part. Header part contains XML body signed with private key and certificate and digest value of body. I have to validate the incoming XML, my question is how to get field values in Header part?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a SOAP Handler to do the job or simply issue a .getHeader() on SOAPMessage instance.
detailed [here](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Working-with-Headers-in-JAX-WS-SOAPHandlers.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! But I always get MessageCreationException: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1] Message: Content is not allowed in prolog. I thought I have to add header fields to response POJO class, seems incoming message is itself broken and couldn't be parsed. How to handle xml before its parsed, just to delete all invalid chars in xml if any? thanks!

Comment: are you getting any message to your SOAPHAndler ? or can you monitor the http traffic ?

Comment: No, I guess I am not getting any message to SOAPHandler, (Boolean) messagecontext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY) value is always true, just checking it with System.out.println if messageHandle method is invoked, and all messages are sent through https protocol, so I can't read incoming xml, even if I use sniffer.